# Why would Android display "Security policy prevents use of unsecure networks" message?

Tags: samsung, wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, connection-issues, system-error

When ***disconnecting*** a non-rooted stock Samsung Android Nougat (7.0) device from a WPA2 WiFi connection, Android briefly displayed the following message:

> Security policy prevents use of unsecure networks.

An internet search found [a thread with someone reporting the same issue](https://old.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS7/comments/7f8ukt/security_policy_restricts_the_use_of_unsecured/), but no resolution was provided.

Why would Android (or perhaps something in Samsung's ROM?) be presenting this message?

Comment: What is the form of this message? A Toast, a Dialog, a Notification? You can look into the logcat and repeat the steps that leads to that message. Something might show as the caller for that message. Also, what device administrators do you currently have enabled? // There is a suggestion here. See if that helps. https://www.googlenestcommunity.com/t5/Chromecast/Security-policy/m-p/201791/highlight/true#M21181

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/samsung/comments/sprhbf/how_to_get_around_security_policy_prevents_use_of/) or [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.phonearena.com/news/disable-secure-wi-fi-notification-samsung-galaxy_id115189&ved=2ahUKEwjulvq9oqX7AhVw-HMBHXE-BB4QFnoECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0yOQ_jUN3WoRXaKRB_zGha)//

Comment: //or [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-watch-active-2/985946-security-policy-prevents-connection-wifi-active-2-a.html&ved=2ahUKEwjulvq9oqX7AhVw-HMBHXE-BB4QFnoECDYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0vXORbtATK0efQW32_3d2S)